# Error "no such file or directory" when using os.chdir in Flask

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I can boot the app up with Flask, it loads and displays localhost viewing info, then immediately quits with the error:

```
can't open file 'server.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

This is normally what you get when there is no file of that name in the folder, but there definitely is in this case as it successfully loads it initially

EDIT: Adding code for `server.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from services.controller import Controller

app = Flask(__name__)
path = '/Users/bhouwens/some/path'
ctrl = Controller(path)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    stats = {'path' : path}

    return jsonify(stats)

@app.route('/task-runners')
def task_runners():
    return jsonify({'task_runners': ctrl.task_runners})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Are the permissions of the file correct? You could add an ls -l output for the file and the command line you are using in case the error is there?

Comment: How do you run the code. Do you just type `python server.py` or do you run the app with gunicorn or mod_wsgi ..? Is there a traceback for the errormessage? Where do you see the errormessage? On the shell or in a logfile?

Comment: Yip just `python server.py`, error message in shell. I've narrowed it to a problem with `os.chdir` in the `Controller` module which, for some new and unexplained reason, crashes the server. My guess is it's trying to continue serving from the new dir, even though I only want to access files there

Comment: Could you show the Controller code also please? It does sound like the problem is in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, `os.chdir` from within a Flask app doesn't seem possible without breaking the server.

In my case, I'm trying to read a file in another directory using another module, where the path to the directory is passed into the module as a parameter in this line:

```
ctrl = Controller(path)
```

I've discovered that the `open` function that Python makes available can open files in other directories, so I got around this issue by using

```
with open(path + '/file_to_open.txt', 'r') as file:
```

from the `Controller` module.

Hopefully this helps someone else who runs into the same problem.

Comment: It is the right way to open a file in another folder. Use `os.path.join(path, 'file_to_open.txt')`. The `chdir` has several side effects.

Answer (score 1):

Like you already discovered, you can't do `chdir`.

```
import os
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
os.chdir('..')

app.run(debug=True)
```

When you execute this file, this is the output:

```
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
* Restarting with stat
/usr/bin/python: can't open file 'example.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what causes this issue, but if you check `app.root_path` after an `os.chdir()`, you would find it messed up, changing `app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT']` doesn't solve this either, you need to change `app.root_path` attribute manually with the new directory path, you can do it while initializing the flask app like so `app = Flask.flask(__name__, root_path=BASE_DIR)`, but you can also change it at any time while flask is running.

Without doing so, Flask does this:

if your app was at ***~/one/two/three/app.py*** and you try to run the app from ***~/one*** , doing an `os.chdir()` to `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` inside the app would result the  `app.root_path` to be equal to `'~/one/two/three/two/three'`, it basically doubles the portion of the path left between the location where you called the app and the app file itself, and if you were running the app from ***~/one/two/three/four/five*** and doing `os.chdir()` to `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` inside the app this would result `app.root_path` to be equal to `'~/one'` ,i.e truncates the number of directories it's far from the app file starting from the app.py directory and going backwards.

**`os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` equals `'~/one/two/three'`**

Weird bug :(